# Append a carriage return to a textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, objective-c

I have a thirdparty peripheral that is capturing barcode data.
I am inserting the barcode text into a textbox on a uiWebView.

I would like to append a carriage return to the end of the text to call the default button within the panel on the web page.
Or I would like to press the ASP:Button using javascript from the objective-c code once the barcode text has been entered in the textbox.

objective-c code:

```
NSString *jScriptString;
jScriptString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var field = document.activeElement;""field.value='%@';", barcode] ;
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jScriptString];
```

website:

```
<asp:Panel ID="panel" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnAdd">
<asp:TextBox ID="tbNewInput" runat="server" Wrap="False" TabIndex="1" ValidationGroup="Add">
</asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" TabIndex="1" Text="Add"/>
</asp:Panel>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a javascript function on the website that clicks the button, and append that to the end of the javascript string sent from objective-c:

In website:

```
function clickButton() {
    $('id^=["btnAdd_"]').click();
}
```

In objective-c, append to the string:

```
jScriptString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var field = document.activeElement;""field.value='%@';clickButton();", barcode] ;
```

If jQuery isn't available, you can do it with native javascript as well, though I don't know the syntax off the top of my head.